# How do I out put the JSON format for other website?

Tags: c#, jquery

How do I out put the JSON format for other website?
I wrote the code below. I've tried to retrieve the information from the JSON server but it didn't return anything back.

JSON SERVER

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
      Response.ContentType = "application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8";
      Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
      //Response.Expires = 0;
     // Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + ".js");
    }
</script>
({
 'color': 'blue',
            'animal': { 'dog': 'friendly' }
})
```

**calling JSON SERVER**

```
  var testurl_a = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?"
var testurl_b = "http://www.xxxxxx.com/myaccount/jsonserver.aspx?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?"

$.getJSON(testurl_b, function (data) {
    alert("JSON Data from testurl_b"); //IS NOT WORKING
});

$.getJSON(testurl_a,function (data) {
        alert("JSON Data from testurl_a Result--->>>"+ data.title); //IS WORKING
 });
```

Comment: It should be noted that JSON should use double quotes (`"`) and not single quotes (`'`). Some JSON interpreters may fail if single quotes are used.

Comment: Put the request (http://www.JSONServer.com/myaccount/jsonserver.aspx) in your browser.  What do you get?

Comment: Wow, about six of us leapt in to fix that formatting. SO human race condition, so to speak.

Comment: Lou, this is what i got. 
({
 "color": "blue",
            "animal": { "dog": "friendly" }
});

Answer (score 2):

Your server-side JSON generator needs to implement the [JSONP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), like this:

```
<%=Request.QueryString["callback"]%>({
 "color": "blue",
            "animal": { "dog": "friendly" }
});
```

Comment: Both the client AND the server need to implement JSONP for it to work properly.

Comment: @darwin Try `<%=Request.QueryString["jsoncallback"]%>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you're not getting a response back is because of cross-domain issues. To get around this, use [JSONp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) instead.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
      Response.ContentType = "application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8";
      Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
      //Response.Expires = 0;
     // Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + ".js");
    }
</script>
callback({
 'color': 'blue',
            'animal': { 'dog': 'friendly' }
})
```

And your client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Test</title>
<head>
  <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function callback(data) {
    // Your callback code goes here.
}
-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.JSONServer.com/myaccount/jsonserver.aspx?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if the URL includes the string "callback=?" in the URL, the request is automatically treated as JSONP by jQuery. Of course he still does need to deal with this in his handler.

Comment: I GOT IT. just the json format
simply change to  remove the ( and ) in the data format. Don't know why yet but i'll stick with this rule